# trying to validate an entry for a date and loop through for each shift of an employee but getting infinite loop

Tags: c++, loops, date, while-loop

I'm trying to validate an entry for a date and loop through for each shift of an employee but getting infinite loop when the entry is invalid and when the entry is valid its not looping through the function again for the other shifts its just terminating the code after the date is entered.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
char employeeName[20];
int i;
char trash[10000];
int employeeNumber =1;
int noShiftsWorked;
int currentShift;
int day,month,year;
int date;
while(employeeNumber !=0){//loop to go through process for each employee
printf("please enter employees name:");
scanf ("%s",employeeName);


while (1)//loop to insure user puts in a valid number for the number of shifts worked by the employee
    {
    printf("How many shifts did %s work this week?",employeeName);
        fflush(stdout);

        if (1 == scanf("%d", &noShiftsWorked))

          break;

        /* scanf failed: clear the bad input from stdin */

        if (NULL == fgets(trash, sizeof(trash), stdin))  /* NOTE: assumes 1 entry per line and no line longer than 10000 characters */
          exit((fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected EOF or error!\n"), 1));

        puts("You did not enter a valid number");
    }

for(currentShift=1;currentShift<noShiftsWorked+1;currentShift++){
    while(date!=1){
        printf("Enter the date of shift %d in format dd/mm/yyyy",currentShift);

    scanf ("%d/%d/%d",day,month,year);
    int IsValidDate(int,int,int);
    date = IsValidDate(year,month,day);
    }
}
}



return 0;
}

int IsValidDate(int year, int month, int day)
{
unsigned int leap;
unsigned char mon_day[] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

/* check the rang of the year */
if ((year < 1) || (year >= 3200))
{
    return 0;
}

if ((month < 1) || (month > 12))
{
    return 0;
}

/* if it's leap year */
if (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0))
{
    leap = 1;
}
else
{
    leap = 0;
}

mon_day[1] += leap;

if ((day > mon_day[month - 1]) || (day < 1))
{
    return 0;
}

return 1;
}
```

I seems as though the check is working correctly but what I want the code to do when the date check runs is malfunctioning in both valid and invalid cases

Comment: `while(date!=1){` First time through this is uninitialized because of `int date;`. On subsequent iterations of the `for` loop, it will be `1` because of previous call to `IsValidDate()`. You need to reset it: `date = 0; while (date != 1) { ... }` Or change to `do/while` loop.

Comment: Prefer to use `std::string` for text; that will cause you to use `std::cin` and `std::cout` as well.

Comment: Did you try debugging the code?

Comment: Note: Debuggers eat infinite loops for breakfast. run the program in the debugger. Wait for it to stop proceeding, then pause execution and step your way through the loop a few times, watching what happens and why the exit condition is never met.

Comment: I've tried set it as 0 both at the start and inside the for loop but before the while loop and I get the same thing. an infinite loop with "enter a valid date" when the date is wrong and the code terminates when its right

Comment: Just noticed another error: `scanf ("%d/%d/%d",day,month,year);` You need to pass pointers there: `scanf ("%d/%d/%d",&day,&month,&year);`

Comment: adding pointers worked for when the input is correct it goes onto the next shift correctly but still loops when a non valid date is inputted